# Dynamic color changing feature

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

https://www.evdemimar.com/oturma-odasi-renk-secimi/

Look this website and the feature. If you click on the color the wall color is changing dynamically.

how to do this feature.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cut out the image's background in software such as Photoshop and save it as a transparent PNG;
2. Place this image inside an HTML div;
3. Change background of the div dynamically using jQuery:

jQuery:

```
    $( '.colour-1' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( 'div.foo').css( 'background-color', '#00CCFF' );
    } );

    $( '.colour-2' ).on( 'click', function() {
       $( 'div.the-one-that-contains-the-img').css( 'background-color', '#999999' );
    } );
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="foo">
        <img src="transparent-background-room-image.png" />
    </div>
```